# How to Use Conditionals in JS Find Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm wondering how to use an if statement in the *JS* `find` function? 
My goal here is when these values do not match to `addClass("filtered-out")` to the elements in my cars array.

```
cars.map(car => active_filters.find(x =>
    if (car.attr(x.id) !== x.value)
        return car.addClass("filtered-out");
));
```

Comment: `find()` expects true/false to be returned.  Elements that return true will be included in the results of the method.

Comment: This code does not seem to be using `find` (or `map`) correctly... [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is meant to, well, find an element in an array that causes the function to return true. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is meant to produce a new array. If you want to iterate through these arrays, I suggest using a loop, or [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: What is the value of `cars` and what is the value of `active_filters`?

Comment: The answer to your question, by the way, is to wrap the body of your arrow function in curly braces: `.find(x => { if ... })`. However, from the looks of it your code needs more work than that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know logic you coded is true or not, but you can use simple loop and check condition.

```
cars.forEach(function(car) {
  for (var i = 0; i < active_filters.length; i ++) {
    if (car.attr(active_filters[i]['id']) !== active_filters[i]['value']) {
      car.addClass("filtered-out");
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

Or something like this

```
cars.forEach(function(car) {

  var found = active_filters.find(function(el) {
    return car.attr(el['id']) === el['value'];
  });

  if (!found) {
    car.addClass("filtered-out");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Saeed. For some reason I'm getting an error on the line of for loop. Is this syntax correct?

Comment: Honestly I just wrote this example to show you what I said, and do not run it. let me modify it.

Comment: Check it now @Michael

Comment: Your welcome, you can accept the answer if it is true. Good luck! @Michael

Comment: Hey Saeed - When using the loop it seems to be very heavy on performance. Is it possible to use something similar to what I have in my example: `cars.map(car => active_filters.find(x => car.attr(x.id) !== x.value));` But somehow addClass to when .find is false? Sorry if this is confusing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170394/discussion-between-saeed-ataee-and-michael).

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
cars.map(car => active_filters.find(x =>
    if (car.attr(x.id) !== x.value)
        return car.addClass("filtered-out");
));
```

has multiple problems. First, you do not assign the result of `.map()` to anything, so it is a useless calculation, except for adding the class where appropriate. Second, for the input of `car` you get the result of `find()` as a result, but `.find()` returns the first index where the expression is true or `undefined`. However, your expression will possibly be always `undefined`, because if the condition if `false`, then you do not even have a `return` statement. Whereas, if the condition is `true`, then you return whatever `addClass()` returns. If `.addClass()` returns something else, then `find()` will return that as long as the condition is `true`. Finally, you mix up your structural changes with your search finder, which is generally not a good idea, because it mixes concerns that should be separate.

This is an example code that may be of help:

```js
let active_filters = {
    ["between 2-7"] : function(item) {
        let val = parseInt(item.innerText);
        return (2 <= val) && (val <= 7);
    },
    "odd" : function(item) {
        return parseInt(item.innerText) % 2;
    }
};

let cars = [...document.querySelectorAll(".car")];

cars.forEach(function(item) {
    for (let key in active_filters) {
        if (!active_filters[key](item)) {
            item.classList.add("filtered_out");
            continue;
        }
    }
});

let finalCars = cars.filter(item => !item.classList.contains("filtered_out"));

console.log(finalCars);
```

```css
.car {
    background-color: green;
}

.car.filtered_out {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="car">1</div>
<div class="car">2</div>
<div class="car">3</div>
<div class="car">4</div>
<div class="car">5</div>
<div class="car">6</div>
<div class="car">7</div>
<div class="car">8</div>
```

Explanation:

- I have created a few `div` elements just so that we have some context
- I'm coloring the cars based on whether they fulfill all the filters
- I have defined an `active_filters` object, which is of key-value pairs, the key being the name of the filter and the value being the value it evaluates to with an input named `item`
- I loop `cars`

  - For each car, I loop `active_filters`

    - If the car does not fulfill the current filter then

      - I add the `filtered_out` class to it
      - `continue`
- I search for the `cars` having the `filtered_out` `class` and log the result.